# Unable to access Apple Developer Accounts in Visual Studio due to "updated Apple Developer Program License Agreement" dialog

Tags: ios, visual-studio, maui, apple-developer-account

I was unable to access information in Tools | Options | Xamarin | Apple Accounts due to a login error.  I duly went and accepted the agreement and continued to get the error (pictured below).  I restarted Visual Studio (17.8.3) - no luck.  I even removed my account - no luck: got the same error when adding my API key in again.

How to fix this?

[image: Visual Studio 2022 (17.8.3) modal preventing use of Apple Developer Accounts]

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the same error also appears when the App Store Connect site wants you to update other information.  I hunted around and found I needed to enter in an address on the App Store Connect site under Agreements, Tax and Banking.

That fixed things right up.